Use deployment-setting file to update connection references for different environments in Power Platform
I'm trying to use a deployment-setting.json file to import solutions to different environments (via pipeline). I'm struggling to work out how to use a different connection reference in each environment, are they manually created first and then use the id from that? I assumed when importing the solution as managed, these would be overwritten.
I've been referring to this document by Microsoft, the environment variables works fine as the values are just updated in different deployment-settings files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/conn-ref-env-variables-build-tools#deployment-settings-file
Any ideas how this is done?
Example from the website on how the connection references are in deployment-settings.json file:
  "ConnectionReferences": [
    {
      "LogicalName": "tst_sharedtst5fcreateuserandjob5ffeb85c4c63870282_b4cc7",
      "ConnectionId": "",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_tst-5fcreateuserandjob-5ff805fab2693f57dc"
    },
    {
      "LogicalName": "tst_SharepointSiteURL",
      "ConnectionId": "",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline"
    },
    {
      "LogicalName": "tst_AzureDevopsConnRef",
      "ConnectionId": "",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_visualstudioteamservices"
    },
    {
      "LogicalName": "tst_GHConn",
      "ConnectionId": "",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_github"
    }
  ]

Expecting connection references to change per environment.
